# Query to Output SQL table to Excel or CSV

Tags: sql, sql-server, export, output

I have been trying to export my table to a csv through a SQL query and no luck.

The attempt was using the OUTPUT function but I got an error. Below is the query:

```
SELECT * FROM [table]; 
OUTPUT TO 'C:\\folder\\new_data.csv' 
    FORMAT TEXT
    QUOTE '"'
    WITH COLUMN NAMES;
```

This was the error:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 81
Incorrect syntax near 'OUTPUT'.
Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 84
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table 
expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the 
previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.
```

Am I not using the OUTPUT function correctly and is there an alternative query in SQL?

Comment: the ";" after the SELECT terminates the statement. So you have two statements here:
SELECT ...;
and
OUTPUT TO ...;
Remove the semicolon after the select and see if that works.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Thanks, when I remove the semicolon there are still red squiggly lines underlining `TO` and `COLUMN`. This is the error: `Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 88
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'TO'.
Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 91
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.`

Answer (score 0):

I actualy use `SQLCMD` command but there is 7 other ways please check link below:

[EXPORT](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Export/147145/)

OR

Use [BCP utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-2017)

The -c argument specifies character output, as opposed to SQL's native binary format; this defaults to tab-separated values, but -t , changes the field terminator to commas. -T specifies Windows authentication ("trusted connection"), otherwise use -U MyUserName -P MyPassword.

This doesn't export column headers by default. You need to use a UNION ALL for headers

Comment: Thanks, think there is a way I can call that SQL cmd script directly from SSMS? Basically I want to just run a sql query that will do all the data manipulation and export at the end without me clicking anything

Comment: I found this hope this is what you want

Answer (score 0):

Why you are trying to do with query. Download some client for SQL , as I know every client provide a feature to export data in various format.

But for complete the answer , you can use SQL Managament Studio for export or object explorer.

I dont want to take credit for this , so you can follow this link for how to do it

https://www.tutorialgateway.org/export-data-from-sql-to-csv/

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking to do it with a query so that I can automate the process entirely in SQL without clicking anything.